# Getting HasUniqueRoleAssignments with the graph API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph

Is it possible to get HasUniqueRoleAssignments with Graph API or do you have to use the SharePoint REST API?

I tried:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/XXX-7386-4E2B-9506-A66FB82EA48B/lists/XXXX-3b4b-423d-9240-XXX/items?expand=fields

Gaves me following:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't have GRAPH api to check permissions for SharePoint objects....you have to rely on SharePoint REST API. Below end point can be use.

```
/sites/blackwidow/_api/Web/Lists(@v0)/Items(@v1)?&@v0=guid'12321313-213-223-2323-2323123'&@v1=1&$select=hasuniqueroleassignments
```

This will return true or false based, $select property will work at site, web, list and list item level.

Hope this is useful...